# Как поменять название файла, не изменив расширение?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой простой код:

```
$file = 'http://site.ru/photo.jpg';
echo basename($file));
```

Как мне изменить название файла так, чтобы не менялось расширение?
В переменной file файлы меняются, поэтому нужно заменить название у всех других файлов, а не просто заменой photo на другое слово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = 'http://site.ru/photo.jpg';
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext = strtok($ext, '?'); //удаляет вопросительный знак и все символы после него
$newname = 'имяфайла.' . $ext;

echo str_replace(basename($file), $newname, $file);

?>
```

Comment: А если у файла расширение вот такое: icon.jpg?1545064977 ? Как можно убрать все, что после расширения?

Comment: @Stop-TussiN добавил в ответ